# Looking for stdout and stderr of a container for .net core

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, containers

Is it right to say the below code will send the custom logs to stdout and stderr of a docker container in .net core?

```
console.Writeline(...)
console.error(..)
```

Comment: did you try it? if not, try it.

Answer (score 8):

If you mean `Console.WriteLine()`, yes:

> Writes the specified string value, followed by the current line terminator, **to the standard output stream**.
>   – https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa324763(v=vs.71).aspx

There is no such method as `Console.Error()`, but there is the [`Console.Error` stream property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.error?view=netframework-4.7.2) (which is stderr), with which you can use `WriteLine`:

```
Console.Error.WriteLine("Oh no!");
```

(There is also `Console.Out`, which is the stdout stream.)

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. Does it mean we dont have any means to send error information to stderr?

Comment: `Console.Error` is stderr.

Comment: Thanks for the help.